Unmet dependancies for python3-samba packages on debian 11 (osmc)
I'm trying to upgrade python3-samba from 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5 armhf to 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6 armhf, yet, when trying to do so I'm getting the following error :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6 is installed
                 Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). 

Now when I'm executing apt --fix-broken install I'm getting the following error :
:/home/osmc# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-samba
Recommended packages:
  python3-gpg
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-samba
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2348 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 55436 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-samba_2%3a4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6_armhf.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-samba.prerm: 6: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: old python3-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-samba_2%3a4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-samba.postinst: 6: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-samba_2%3a4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 


my debian version is :
/home/osmc# uname -a
Linux osmc 5.15.92-1-osmc #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 25 00:03:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?

What happens if you manually run py3clean and py3compile? They should output a brief usage summary, but it seems they’re broken on your system. If they are indeed broken, apt reinstall python3-minimal should fix them.

Hi Stephen thanks, for the reply.  py3clean returns :
bash: /usr/bin/py3clean: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied . py3compile returns :
bash: /usr/bin/py3compile: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied.

Finally apt reinstall python3-minimal returns :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6 is to be installed
Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u6 is to be installed.  Probably you are right. Is there another way to fix this?

As it seems the installation was not working due to wrong python version of the system I had installed at a point.
I've used sudo update-alternatives --config python3 and made python3.9 primary. After that the installation worked perfectly.

Your Python interpreter is broken, you need to reinstall it; since python3-samba is also broken, you need to install it simultaneously:
apt install --reinstall python3-minimal libpython3.9-minimal python3.9-minimal python3-samba

Since your setup appears to be too broken for this to work, you can try reverting the required packages manually:
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.9.2-3_armhf.deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.9/libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_armhf.deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.9/python3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_armhf.deb
dpkg -i python3-minimal_3.9.2-3_armhf.deb libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_armhf.deb python3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_armhf.deb

Once that’s done, you should be able to upgrade python3-samba or remove it, as you wish.

sudo apt install --reinstall python3.9-minimal libpython3.9-minimal python3.9-minimal python3-samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Recommended packages:
python3-gpg
The following packages will be upgraded:
python3-samba
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2348 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libpython3.9-minimal:armhf

I do have python 3.11.3 installed, yet, even if I change 3.9 to 3.11 I get E: Unable to locate package libpython3.11-minimal
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpython3.11-minimal'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpython3.11-minimal'
E: Unable to locate package python3.11-minimal
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.11-minimal'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.11-minimal'

Ah, now we’re getting to what may be the root cause... How did you install Python 3.11? Replacing the system’s Python interpreter tends to break things.

I think you are right Stephen. I've used it in order to install a small py program for automatic downloading I've wrote. Is there a way where I can disable python3-samba so as not to be installed and then remove it? If this is done, I believe I will be able to update the rest of the system.

What I mean is that I would like to remove it from the installation queue and if possible then remove it as a service.

There isn’t really an “installation queue”; see my updated answer for another approach.

I've resolved the issue. As you said it was a python issue. I've used sudo update-alternatives --config python3 and made python 3.9 primary. Then the installation worked like a charm. Thank you for your help Stephen!
